# Google Storage Transfer Service: how to move files to an external bucket outside of the current project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I need to transfer files from my bucket to another bucket once a day. The destination bucket is outside of my project.

So I've tried to create a Storage Transfer Service job but obiovsly I get the following authorization error:

> Failed to obtain the location of the GCS bucket "destination-bucket-name" Additional details: project-xxxxxxxxxxxxx@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

I have the service account key json to access the external bucket, but how can I use it with Storage Transfer Service?

Comment: Based on your error, it needs the permission `storage.buckets.get`, have you enabled it? You can check this documentation on [predefind legacy roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles) and [agentless transfer permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/iam-cloud).

Comment: The storage transfer service account seems to be the default service account for the storage transfer service, but it isn't listed in the service accounts list in the IAM & administration panel, then I can't neither modify it nor add that permission. To bypass this permission issue, for now I have implemented by my own a cloud function that gets the object, then it upload that object to the other bucket and delete the object from the source bucket

Comment: Please post this as an answer so that this would be helpful for other community members with similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlessioInnocenzi mentioned in the comment section:

> To bypass this permission issue, for now I have implemented by my own a cloud function that gets the object, then it upload that object to the other bucket and delete the object from the source bucket.